# Union results of two databases query

Tags: mysql, union

I have two databases with two similar tables:

**Database1**

```
id         date              value   
---       -----------        --------- 
1          2016-05-01        234  
2          2016-05-02        567  
3          2016-05-03        800
4          2016-05-03        300
```

**Database2**

```
id         date              value   
---       -----------        --------- 
1          2016-04-20        900  
2          2016-05-02        455
3          2016-05-03        90
4          2016-05-02        855
```

I have this query for each database:

```
SELECT date, SUM(value) As TOTAL FROM tablename   
WHERE date >= DATE_SUB( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 1 YEAR )   
GROUP BY date ORDER BY date
```

Which return these results:

```
        Database1                              Database2
 date          TOTAL                      date          TOTAL  
------       ---------                   -------        -------  
2016-05-01     234                       2016-04-20       900  
2016-05-02     567                       2016-05-02       1310  
2016-05-03     1100                      2016-05-03       90
```

Now I want a query that will combine these two results base on date, My expected output is:

```
        Cobined Results 
 date          TOTAL_DB1      TOTAL_DB2  
------       ---------        ----------   
2016-04-20       0               900     
2016-05-01     234                 0         
2016-05-02     567              1310  
2016-05-03    1100                90
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `union all`, then do aggregation by group `date`:

```
SELECT `date`, sum(TOTAL_DB1) as TOTAL_DB1, sum(TOTAL_DB2) as TOTAL_DB2 
FROM (
    SELECT date, SUM(value) As TOTAL_DB1, 0 AS TOTAL_DB2 FROM Database1   
    WHERE date >= DATE_SUB( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 1 YEAR )   
    GROUP BY date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT date, 0 AS TOTAL_DB1, SUM(value) As TOTAL_DB2 FROM Database2  
    WHERE date >= DATE_SUB( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 1 YEAR )   
    GROUP BY date
) t
GROUP BY `date`
ORDER BY `date`
```

[<kbd>**Check Demo Here**</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/935d3/1)